# How do I rename the computer name/root in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, profile

I'm new to Mac. I would like to rename the computer name/root title that shows up when I open the terminal. Usually it's like computername:~ xxx$

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this in a terminal

```
sudo scutil --set HostName [NewHostNameHere]
```

Or if you want to do it via the GUI, do this

Apple Menu > System Preferences > Sharing > change the computer name (near the top of the window).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I changed the hostname via the terminal. I confirmed by running the hostname command. However, the [computername:~ xxx$ ] has not changed.

Comment: did you try the 2nd method I listed?  Also, you will need to open a new prompt in order to see the change or at least reload the terminal and it should show up.

Comment: Close the terminal and open a new instance to see the changes!